# Understanding and rearranging table in Awesome CV

Tags: tables, document-classes, awesome-cv

I am using Awesome-CV right now and want to adjust one of the section codes to a different format. Currently the format has the date on the left, with the position and description next, and then the location:

[image: Example image]

With the code for the section looking like:

```latex
% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}
```

And I call upon it as such:

```latex
\begin{cvhonors}
    \cvhonor
    {Dean's List} % Award
    {Awarded each semester for being in the top 30\% of students.} % Event
    {Boston, M.A.} % Location
    {2014-2018} % Date(s)
...
```

However, **my goal is to remove the location field and have the date field on the right end** as such:

[image: Ideal scenario]

I am fairly new to latex and I think the way to change this would be in the \begin{tabular} line but the syntax is confusing me and I'm not sure where the \cvhonor arguments are going into the environment and how to rearrange them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here are the definitions of C L and R:

```latex
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the description is shorter than a single line, you could use the following newly defined `\mycvhonor` command:

```
\documentclass{awesome-cv}

\newcommand{\mycvhonor}[3]{%
   \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} \hfill \honordatestyle{#3} \\}

\begin{document}
    \mycvhonor
    {Dean's List} % Award
    {Awarded each semester for being in the top 30\% of students.} % Event
    {2014-2018} % Date(s)
\end{document}
```